# How to get `context.Context` from `workflow.Context`?

Tags: go, cadence-workflow

I'm implementing a Cadence Workflow that needs to call functions with `context.Context` parameters. How do I go about getting a `context.Context` from the `workflow.Context`? Is it just a matter of `ctx.(*context.Context)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not `context.Context`.

You should **never** write any workflow code that uses `context.Context` at all. All the calls that needs `context.Context` should be written within workflow activity or local activity for determinism.

In other words, **Workflow code should only contain logic to orchestrate/manage other workflow entities like activities/childWF/Signal/etc.**

`workflow.Context` is a special data structure for worker to pass in workflow run-time information during workflow execution. For example, workflowID and runID. It happens to call `Context` just because this **looks** very similar with Golang style. Other than that, it has nothing directly related to `context.Context`.

In Java client, there is no `workflow.Context` and the way that worker pass through these data is via `ThreadLocal`.

If you really want to pass through some KV data from external to workflow code, you can use context propagation: https://github.com/uber-common/cadence-samples/tree/master/cmd/samples/recipes/ctxpropagation