# How to pass workflow.Context to the Cadence activity

Tags: go, cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I would like to put `workflow.Sleep` call in one of my Cadence activities to be able to test it properly (and simulate error result coming from `Sleep` function).

Two important things which I noticed before implementing:

- `context.Context` and `workflow.Context` [are separate types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187090/how-to-get-context-context-from-workflow-context).
- First parameter of each activity - `context.Context` - [is optional and can be omitted](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/go-client/activities/)

My tries:

**1. First try**

```
import "go.uber.org/cadence/workflow"

// Activity:    
func (s *MyActivities) WorkflowSleep(_ context.Context, workflowCtx workflow.Context, duration time.Duration) error {
    return workflow.Sleep(workflowCtx, duration)
}

// In workflow; ctx has type workflow.Context:
    err := workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, myActivities.WorkflowSleep, ctx, duration).Get(ctx, nil)
```

Error:

> "error":"unable to decode the activity function input bytes with error: unable to decode argument: 0, *internal.Context, with json error: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type internal.Context for function

**2. Second try**

```
import "go.uber.org/cadence/workflow"

// Activity:    
func (s *MyActivities) WorkflowSleep(workflowCtx workflow.Context, duration time.Duration) error {
    return workflow.Sleep(workflowCtx, duration)
}

// In workflow; ctx has type workflow.Context:
    err := workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, myActivities.WorkflowSleep, duration).Get(ctx, nil)
```

Error:

> "PanicError":"reflect: Call with too few input arguments"

**Question**

Is it possible to use `workflow.Sleep` inside any activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use workflow.Sleep inside any activity?

No, it's NOT allowed to use `workflow.Sleep` in activity code.

`Workflow.Sleep` is only allowed in workflow code.
More general, all the APIs in `workflow` package are ONLY allowed in workflow code.

The workflow code will be executed within decision task, and the workflow threads/coroutines(special kind of goroutines) are managed by Cadence. This is how those APIs in `workflow` package works. Without [decision tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904129/what-exactly-is-a-cadence-decision-task/63964726#63964726)  and [workflow threads/coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71356668/how-does-multi-threading-works-in-cadence-temporal-workflow), those API won't work properly.

The activity code on the other hand, is just purely normal code that you should use regular native library or dependency to implement the logic. For example, you can use `time.Sleep` in activity code.